# Policy gradient - and auto-differentiation (Pytorch/Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, pytorch, policy-gradients

In policy gradient, we have something like this: 
[image]

Is my understanding correct that if I apply log cross-entropy on the last layer, the gradient will be automatically calculated as per formula above?

Comment: what are inputs of crossentropy? logits and action or logits and target?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just take the cross-entropy loss of the last layer and take the gradient with respect to it. The actual action will be the target.

For example, in PyTorch: apply [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) on the last layer (no need of doing softmax, as it is done implicitly by this function)